# ObjectBox: Abort Transaction?

Tags: android, transactions, objectbox

How can I abort my write Transaction in ObjectBox if one of my actions fails? I do not see anything available from within the Runnable or the boxStore or one of the boxes to abort a transaction. I don't want half of my actions to get applied and half to not get applied if, for example, I get an unrelated I/O error while running my transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception. E.g.

```
try {
    boxStore.runInTx(() -> {
       for(User user: allUsers) {
         if(user.isValid()) box.put(user);
         else throw new UserInvalidException();
       }
    });
} catch (UserInvalidException e) {
    // TX is aborted
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, but the compiler claims that the Exception is unhandled.

Comment: I think I just found my solution from https://docs.objectbox.io/transactions: **callInTx**: Like runInTx(Runnable), but allows returning a value and throwing an exception.

Comment: UserInvalidException would be a RuntimeException